# Loop over Object and return the length of each key cumulatively in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I would like to loop over and return the cumulative length of each key in an array. Below is the object and the ideal output:

```
const books = {
    "book_1": ["image-1", "image-2", "image-3"], // 3
    "book_2": ["image-1"], // 1
    "book_3": ["image-1", "image-2"] // 2
}

// Ideal Output
[3, 4, 6]
```

I know it's not possible to loop over an object, but I've used `Object.key()` and then `.reduce()` to get the length of each key, I just can't work out how to piece them together. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
const books = {
    "book_1": ["image-1", "image-2", "image-3"], // 3
    "book_2": ["image-1"], // 1
    "book_3": ["image-1", "image-2"] // 2
}

console.log(Object.keys(books).reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue, index) {
  console.log(books[Object.keys(books)[index]].length)
  
  return currentValue;
}, []))
```

Comment: Object doesn't guaranty order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const books = {
    "book_1": ["image-1", "image-2", "image-3"], // 3
    "book_2": ["image-1"], // 1
    "book_3": ["image-1", "image-2"] // 2
}

console.log(Object.entries(books).reduce((acc, [key, array]) => {
  acc.push((acc.slice(-1)[0] || 0) + array.length);
  return acc;
}, []))
```

However ... since key order is not guaranteed, you may end up with

```js
const books = {
    "book_2": ["image-1"], // 1
    "book_1": ["image-1", "image-2", "image-3"], // 3
    "book_3": ["image-1", "image-2"] // 2
}

console.log(Object.entries(books).reduce((acc, [key, array]) => {
  acc.push((acc.slice(-1)[0] || 0) + array.length);
  return acc;
}, []))
```

and you want a particular order I'm guessing - so, sort the keys

```js
const books = {
    "book_2": ["image-1"], // 1
    "book_1": ["image-1", "image-2", "image-3"], // 3
    "book_3": ["image-1", "image-2"] // 2
}

console.log(Object.entries(books).sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b)).reduce((acc, [key, array]) => {
  acc.push((acc.slice(-1)[0] || 0) + array.length);
  return acc;
}, []))
```

Answer (score -1):

It *is* possible to loop over an object though.

```
const books = {
"book_1": ["image-1", "image-2", "image-3"], // 3
"book_2": ["image-1"], // 1
"book_3": ["image-1", "image-2"] // 2
}

let sum = 0;
let arr = [];

for(let i in books){
  sum += books[i].length;
  arr.push(sum);
}

console.log(arr);//[3,4,6]
```

Comment: `// Ideal Output
[3, 4, 6]` - not even close